# PHP Parsedown get all headings

Tags: php, markdown, parsedown

I use [Parsedown](http://parsedown.org/) for transforming my Markdown into HTML like:

```
$pd->text('# My First heading');
```

In want automatically use the first site heading (h1) as an entry for a custom menu. I already had a look into the source, but couldn't figure out a good way to get all headings.

Perhaps there is something in `elements` function. Does anyone has an idea to get all or at least the first heading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Author of [Parsedown](http://parsedown.org/) here.

You should be able to achieve this by creating an extension that overrides the `blockHeader` method. Basically, the overriding method should modify the result of the parent method.

Have a look at the [Parsedown wiki](https://github.com/erusev/parsedown/wiki/Tutorial:-Create-Extensions) for more info.

Answer (score 5):

@tobias-redmann

> couldn't figure out a good way to get all headings

I assume you already solved this problem. But since I had the same problem and came up with the answer, I would like to share some info for those who will confront with the same problem.

### TL;DR

Getting ToC (Table of Contents) w/ Parsedown.

```
<?php

include('Parsedown.php');

class Extension extends Parsedown
{
    public $array_line = array();

    // Override
    protected function blockHeader($Line)
    {
        // Parse $Line to parent class
        $Block = Parsedown::blockHeader($Line);

        // Set headings
        if(isset($Block['element']['name'])){
            $Level = (integer) trim($Block['element']['name'],'h');
            $this->array_line[] = [
                'text'  => $Block['element']['name'],
                'level' => $Level,
            ];
        }

        return $Block;
    }
}

$text = file_get_contents('YourMarkdownFile.md');

$Parsedown   = new Extension();
$string_body = $Parsedown->text($text);
$array_ToC   = $Parsedown->array_line;

print_r($array_ToC);
//echo $string_body;
```

### TS;DR (Details)

First of all, as @emanuil-rusev said, overriding the `blockHeader` method, you can get all the headings from the markdown text.

More specifically, when you call [`text($text)`](https://github.com/erusev/parsedown/blob/master/Parsedown.php#L24-L45) method, it parses the markdown strings given.

While parsing, the [`blockHeader($Line)`](https://github.com/erusev/parsedown/blob/master/Parsedown.php#L470-L498) method will be called every line with an array argument such as below.

```
$Line => [
    "body"   => "# SampleHead",
    "indent" => 0,
    "text"   => "# SampleHead",
]
```

The original (parent) class' `blockHeader($Line)` method converts `$Line` into the following array(`$Block`).

```
$Block => [
    "element" => [
        "name"    => "h1",
        "text"    => "# SampleHead",
        "handler" => "line",
    ],
]
```

So, the easiest way to get all the headings is to store these each time into an array.

### Full script (extension) to get table of contents

See my repo:
https://github.com/KEINOS/parsedown-extension_table-of-contents